# Data is being truncated while storing in database even in LongText data type

Tags: mysql, database, ckeditor, truncate, longtext

I have encountered a strange problem.
I try to save a large content on db where my field is set as **longtext** .

When I post the data and dump it, complete data is being posted.
but when I try to upload it to the database, the data is being truncated.

The Name Datatype and collation looks as below:

```
    description_en  longtext    utf8_general_ci
```

Also, I am using CKEditor for managing the content.
I went through **config.js** file. Everything seemed OK.

What must be the issue here?

P.S.:- The content I am uploading is almost 3100 characters long.